# Find a value based on a matching word and store it

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python, and im just trying to get a feel for the language

I have a file called lion.txt that has this text:

The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the big cats in the genus Panthera and a member of the family Felidae. The commonly used term African lion collectively denotes the several subspecies in Africa. With some males ***exceeding***=**250**/12 kg (550 lb) in weight,[4].

What I want my program to do is search for the keyword ***exceeding*** and write only the value **250** to another file called searched.txt. At very best is it possible to store it as a variable and then print it to another text file?

This is what I have so Far:

```
import os
import re

os.chdir("C:\Python 2016 Training\lionfolder")
f = open("lion.txt", "r")
w = open("searched.txt", "w")

k = [] #Figured a dictionary would be the best way to deal with this?

for line in f:
    if re.match('(.*)exceeding(.*)',  line):
    w.write(k[1] = "line")
```

Is what im asking to do even possible with Python?

Thank you in advance

Regards,
Kevin.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not bad for a first attempt. You're close to a working solution, but missing some critical parts. Try this:

```
import os
import re

f = open('lion.txt', 'r')
w = open('searched.txt', 'w')

for line in f:
    match = re.search('exceeding\=(\d+)', line)
    if match:
        w.write(match.group(1))

w.close()
f.close()
```

There are better ways of doing this, but I have tried to stay as close to your original code as possible, so you don't get lost.